# python and hours formula calculation

Tags: python, math

I have some working code that I altered but I can't seem to get the math right for the hours variable. I think I had to much food for the holidays because I'm coming up with a blank.

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/124894/ (r2)
from Tkinter import *
import time
import pygtk
import gtk
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        hours = int(elap) #cant remember formula 
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)
        sn = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S')                
        self.timestr.set('%02s\n\n%02dh:%02dm:%02ds:%02d' % (sn,hours,minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title( "Stop Watch" )
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/124894/ }}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that minutes = elap / 60?

Comment: That part was included in the code I just wanted to add an hours variable.  I know it looks strange but it seems to work....

Comment: it's elap/60. time() returns floating point representing seconds since the begginning of the epoch so 1.0 is one second 3600.0 is 3600 seconds etc.

Comment: good that downvotes are worth less than upvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer from the equations that `elap` is measured in seconds. Since you are extracting hours into a separate variable, you need to remove them from the minutes tally. And of course you need to follow this through the rest of the calculation since the meaning of `minutes` is changed from the original code.

```
hours = int(elap/3600)
minutes = int((elap-hours*3600)/60)
seconds = int(elap-hours*3600-minutes*60)
hseconds = int((elap-hours*3600-minutes*60-seconds)*100)
```

I think if I was writing this I would modify `elap` as I was going along to reduce the duplication.

```
hours = int(elap/3600)
elap -= hours*3600
minutes = int(elap/60)
elap -= minutes*60
seconds = int(elap)
elap -= seconds
hseconds = int(elap*100)
```

Doing it this way makes it far easier to see what is going on and also easier to modify in future. For example, if you wanted to add days into the mix then all you need to do is graft this onto the beginning of the code:

```
days = int(elap/86400)
elap -= days*86400
```

Now, I've written the code here assuming that `elap` is a `float`, which of course it is in your program. If you were particularly paranoid you would write `elap = float(elap)` before performing the arithmetic.

But I agree with @soulcheck that it's much cleaner to use a library function.

Comment: Your code works fine, but I think it can be made more elegant. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is much easier to work from the other end. You don't need big numbers like `86400` which make code reviewers reach for their calculator app.

```
c = int(elap * 100) # centiseconds
s, c = divmod(c, 100)
m, s = divmod(s, 60)
h, m = divmod(m, 60)
d, h = divmod(h, 24)
print(d, h, m, s, c)
```

or, avoiding the function calls:

```
c = int(elap * 100) # centiseconds
s = c // 100; c %= 100
m = s //  60; s %=  60
h = m //  60; m %=  60
d = h //  24; h %=  24
print(d, h, m, s, c)
```

Comment: +1 That works very well and reads nicely. Now we just need to wait for someone else to come along and trump you with a further "Your code works fine...." comment.  ;-)

Comment: hahahhaah Better more answers than less I say ;-) ...Thanks for your help guys this really helped....

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = int(elap/ 3600)

minutes = int((elap % 3600) / 60)

seconds = int(elap % 60) 

hseconds = int((elap % 1) * 100)
```

Maybe you'll be better off converting it with datetime.fromtimestamp and working with that.

edit: added all the missing formulas

Comment: This is correct so far as it goes but there remains what to do about seconds and hseconds

Comment: i assumed Rick T would notice the pattern ;)

Comment: Yes and thank you all!!!   I'm off to my second thanksgiving feast...thank goodness for sweatpants ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test at the moment, but going by the code `elap` is the amount of seconds passed. Thus, you would divide it by 3600 and with `int()` it gets rounded down. What this means for the previous code is that before it could have, for example, 90 minutes on the clock, but now that should be 1 hour and 30 minutes. So besides calculating the hour, you also have to adjust `minutes`, `seconds` and `hseconds` accordingly.

```
def _setTime(self, elap):
    """ Set the time string to Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
    hours = int(elap/3600)
    minutes = int(elap/60 - hours*60.0)
    seconds = int(elap - hours*3600.0 - minutes*60.0)
    hseconds = int((elap - hours*3600.0 - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)
    sn = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S')                
    self.timestr.set('%02s\n\n%02dh:%02dm:%02ds:%02d' % (sn,hours,minutes, seconds, hseconds))
```

Comment: Your code works fine, but I think it can be made more elegant.